# Ordered Collection maintaining max capacity

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

ideally I need a collection which will be sorted and maintaining max number of elements. Use case: I need to pick top 20 objects from around 100k per minute which will be sorted by some param. It is actually going to be some objects containing some metadata and timings. In case of new value is coming to collection which might be inserted somewhere inside the collection, I need last element to be deleted. Also ideally to be a threadsafe since information posted there and deleted might be propagated in different Threads. Could you point me out if there is an implementation which fits these needs or it sounds like a custom one?

Thank you!

Tried CopyOnWriteArrayList, and tried after insert to remove elements after 20th one. However I am getting an exception that collection was modified before I delete an element

Comment: 1) I don't think there is such collection in standard library - too many custom requirements 2) `However I am getting an exception that collection was modified before I delete an element` - seems like faulty synchronization 3) An idea - use `SortedSet`, fill until 20 elements are in, if `input >= min && input <= max` insert and remove min, don't forget to synchronize.

Comment: `java.util.PriorityQueue` or `com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue` with max size set also may do the trick.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Chaosfire, thank you for the pointing. Tested SortedSet as a TreeSet implementation. Set keeps time as a key and does not keep the same keys(obviously). However I need top 20 even with duplicated keys. Looking for another sorted collection